# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA can't open the certificate file after downloading it on emulator

Tags: performance, mobile, jmeter, certificate

ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA can't open the certificate file after downloading it on emulator

ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA can't open the certificate file after downloading it on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Valid certificate should be normally "opened", you should [check your emulator logs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) for any suspicious entries.

It might be connected with the certificate expiration, by default its life span is [7 days only](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) so if it's expired you won't be able to use it. In this case you will need to delete  `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and `proxyserver.jks` files and re-generate new certificate by launching the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) once again.

Also just importing the certificate might not be sufficient, most probably you will have to amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)